# how do i delete a subdirectory that created by rtmp

Tags: php, nginx, rtmp

My rtmp-module settings as follow:

1. Hls_nested on.
2. Hls_continuous on// once setup seems to disable hls_cleanup.

I just want to delete this subdirectory after the live is over, but the question is the subdirectorys permission is the way to high that php cannot do anything about it, what can i do?

I did some searches and did not find a solution,if i set hls_continuous off then hls_cleanup will get the job done,but of course that is not what i want it.

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot use hls_cleanup option then I think the only way is to use "exec_publish_done", It will automatically execute any command or script when the stream ends gracefully.

`exec_publish_done /path/to/directory;`

Wiki explains it too.
https://github.com/dreamsxin/nginx-rtmp-wiki/blob/master/Directives.md#exec_play_done